# Circuit Diagram of L298N with Arduino

Tags: arduino, l298, arduino-uno

My questions:

1. Am I correct in my schematic if I want to connect L298N to Arduino to drive 2 motors?
2. Are the resistors of 0.5 Ω mandatory? (I saw them in datasheet)
3. Am I missing components in my scheme?

Motors consume 24 volt and max current of 300 mA
L298N allow me to change the sense of rotation or motors
Diodes are 1N5819

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6jLHX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There are a gazillion images on google how to wire these up - just check there and come back if you see a difference that you can't understand.

Comment: hello Andy. I ask that because there is a bunch of different diagrams on google. All of them are different to each other. So thank you for your answer.

Comment: And then we have your circuit (that might be different again) but only you know the design ideas behind it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes with all the basic connections correct, it should work
2. No they are not mandatory but you should use it
3. No, in fact there are many components you don't necessarily need. They are there just to smoothen things out

Same thing:

[image]

Comment: The LEDs and R1 and R2 should be across the motor drive outputs. And 20k is far too large for a 9V motor.